# Search for images that width and height is more than 500

Tags: php, functions

This is my code to get the first image:

```
function get_post_first_image() {
global $post, $posts;
$first_img  = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$content    = get_the_content();
$content    = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
$output     = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $content, $matches); // You must replace data-original to str if you disabled lazy-load images
$first_img  = $matches[1][0];
if(empty($first_img)){ 
    $first_img = "";
}
return $first_img;
}
```

how can convert this code to make its search on the post content for any image width and height more than 500px?
Note: search for the all content not search for the first post only.
Can getimagesize help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your $matches through the getimagesize() function to check it's dimensions, the problem is this function requires a path to the image but your content will provide full URL's so you'll need to see if the image is also saved in your media library and if so grab the relative path only. If a lot of the images are from 3rd party sites it's more complex as you'll need to fetch the image or you would need to use javascript instead.

Example if your images are hosted on your own site:

```
$images = array();

foreach ( $matches[1] as $match ) {

    $attachment_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $match );

    if ( $attachment_id ) {

        $path = get_attached_file( $attachment_id );

        list( $width, $height ) = getimagesize( $path );

        if ( $width > 500 && $height > 500 ) {

            $images[$match];

        }

    }

}

var_dump( $images );
```

Comment: Note that as far as I remember that API function doesn't handle generated image _sizes_. Generic reliable reversal of image URL is far from trivial, I have answer on that somewhere around here....

Comment: Thank you but I can't use get_attached_file because the image that uploaded in the post is uploaded through custom upload system on the frontend, not from wp admin, hope you understand me.